# MSMQ transactional or recoverable

Tags: msmq

I have a question about MSMQ. If I use a non-transactional queue and send message to it with recoverable parameter, message is stored on disc and in case of some problem secure. But if I want pull message from non-transactional queue, is there some mechanism to secure messages to stay in queue in case of some problem (server error, db off...)?

For some reasons I don't want to use transactional queue. Thanks a lot for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a peek-then-receive process to simulate a transaction.

1. Peek message to get content.
2. Use the content as you wish.
3. If step 2 completes then Receive message to effectively delete it.
4. If step 2 fails, execute cleanup code and goto step 1.